# Should this simple structure have an implicit move constructor?

Tags: c++11, language-lawyer

In this test:

```
#include <string>

struct thing {
    std::string name_;
};

class test {
    thing id_;
public:
    test(thing id) : id_{std::move(id)} {}
};
```

I would expect *struct thing* to have an implicit move constructor, so that *class test* can use std::move() to initialise its data member.

Clang version 3.4.1 gives this error:

```
error: no viable conversion from 'typename remove_reference<thing&>::type' (aka 'thing') to 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >')
```

The problem can be solved by adding a move constructor to *struct thing*, which of course means that a converting constructor and an explicitly defaulted copy constructor also needs to be added.

I do not understand why I cannot move *struct thing* around implicitly.

Comment: What compiler are you using? http://ideone.com is compiling just fine. `thing` surely has implicit move constructor, but your compiler interpret `id_{std::move(id)}` as aggregate initialization.

Comment: `id_(std::move(id))` (with parentheses instead of curly braces) works. Waiting for a [tag:language-lawyer] to clear up why aggregate initialization overrides move-construction, or whether it is a bug :)

Comment: @Quentin I have an aggregate initialization blind spot. I could not see it. Thanks, all working now.

Comment: confusing as heck to have [another Richard Smith](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1041090/richard-smith) (one of Clang's primary authors) ask Clang related questions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a brace initialization - `id_{std::move(id)}`. In your case, as though `struct thing` is a POD (plain old data) it means, that C++ compiler tries to initialize the first member - `std::string name_` instead of using a default constructor of `struct thing` object. [Read more about aggregates and PODs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special).

In this case, because of the braces, `class test`'s constructor is equivalent to something like this:

```
class test {
    thing id_;
public:
    test(thing id) {
        id_.name_ = std::move(id); // Notice that this causes
                                   // the "no viable conversion" error
    }
};
```

---

**Solution 1:** You need to declare explicitly that you want to use a default `struct thing`'s constructor by using parenthesis instead of braces:

```
#include <string>

struct thing {
    std::string name_;
};

class test {
    thing id_;
public:
    test(thing id) : id_(std::move(id)) {} // Default c-tor will be used
};
```

---

**Solution 2:** You could also declare a user-defined constructor of `struct thing` to make it non-POD:

```
#include <string>

struct thing {
    std::string name_;
    thing(thing&&) {} // Used-defined move constructor
};

class test {
    thing id_;
public:
    test(thing id) : id_{std::move(id)} {} // You can use braces again
};
```